# OpenMP 4.0 nested task parallelism and GCC 4.9.1

Tags: multithreading, gcc, g++, openmp, g++4.9

I have a code like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single
    {
        int x;
        #pragma omp task depend(inout:x)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
            {
                 #pragma omp task
                 DoComputationOnPartition(i);
            }
            #pragma omp taskwait
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
        {
          #pragma omp task depend(in:x)
          {
             OperateOnPartition(i);
          }
        }
        #pragma omp task depend(inout:x)
        {
           for (int i =1; i < 16; i++) x++;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
        {
          #pragma omp task depend(in:x)
          {
             OperateOnPartition(i);
          }
        }
        #pragma omp taskwait
    }
}
```

And what I find is that the master thread never gets to execute a task of DoComputationOnPartition nested inside the first task. Can someone explain that? It should work, right? The #pragma omp taskwait is an scheduling point so any thread of the team should be able to get a task. The master thread reaches the final taskwait and it should be able to get a nested task. They have long enough duration to allow that.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use variable `x` within 1st/2nd/4th task? Is it intentionally?

Comment: It's there just to provide a correct dependency tracking for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Taskwait waits just for the immediate children, spawning other tasks than the children in the taskwait construct is possible, but risks (much) increasing the latency of taskwait, if you have important amount of work after the taskwait.  If you want to wait for all children + grand children etc., you can use #pragma omp taskgroup construct, or just in these cases leave out the taskwaits and use the (implicit) barrier at the end of single construct.

Answer (score 0):

As per OpenMP 4.0 specification:

> **Binding** A taskgroup region binds to the current task region. The  binding thread set of the taskgroup region is the current team.
>
> **Description** When a thread encounters a taskgroup construct, it starts executing the region. There is an implicit task scheduling
>   point at the end of the  taskgroup region. The current task is
>   suspended at the task scheduling point until all child tasks that it
>   generated in the taskgroup region and all of their descendent tasks
>   complete execution.

So, you mean to put the tasks inside a taskgroup. Well, ok. But it also means a scheduling point, the same as a taskwait.
If libgomp has a problem with that, it is a problem specific of that runtime, not OpenMP as an API. ICC and other runtimes like OmpSs do not have such behaviour problem :-S

Taskgroup only makes sense (as I see it) if you want to wait for all the hierarchy of tasks, but this is not the case.

I think you mean this, right?:

```
 #pragma omp task depend(inout:x)
 {
        #pragma omp taskgroup
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
            {
                 #pragma omp task
                 DoComputationOnPartition(i);
            }
        }
  }
```

The original code has the first taskwait nested, inside another context, so there is only a small group of tasks waiting in that taskwait.